# Unable to detect click in UILabel on right characters in case label contains Emojis

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, touch, textkit

I am using this method to detect click on hashtags and other attributed links in the UILabel.

This code works fine by returning true value in most of the cases but in case the attributed text contains some unicodes like emojis then this methods fails and return false as a value.

I have debugged it and found that that method `layoutManager.glyphIndex(for: locationOfTouchInLabel, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceThroughGlyph: nil)` is providing wrong index value.

```
 public func isTouchInLabelRange(touch: UITouch, label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        guard let attributedText = label.attributedText else {
            return false
        }
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attributedText)

        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.heightTracksTextView = true
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
        let labelSize = label.bounds.size
        textContainer.size = labelSize
        let locationOfTouchInLabel = touch.location(in: label)    

        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.glyphIndex(for: locationOfTouchInLabel, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceThroughGlyph: nil)


        let bufferIndex = 2
        let updatedTargetRange = NSRange.init(location: targetRange.location > bufferIndex ? targetRange.location-bufferIndex : targetRange.location , length: targetRange.length + 2*bufferIndex)

        return NSLocationInRange(Int(indexOfCharacter), updatedTargetRange)

    }
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, it's because the size in utf8/utf16 by default my be different between the two of things (old NSRange in Objective-C vs Range in Swift )

Comment: @Larme ... So should I need to convert the UTF format of the string? Also, what will be the effect of this.... as currently, all the emojis are visible?